# Primefaces Confirm Dialog is not delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, confirm-dialog

this is my delete code:

```
                       <!--Borrar Asesor-->
                        <p:column headerText="Eliminar" exportable="false" style="width:80px">
                            <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" update="asesorTable" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show();" immediate="true">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{asesor}" target="#{eliminarAsesorManagedBean.selectedAsesor}" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                        <!--Fin Borrar Asesor-->
```

This is my confirm dialog:

```
<!--Borrar Asesor Dialogo-->
            <p:dialog id="dlg" widgetVar="dlg" header="Eliminar" modal="true" resizable="false" minWidth="160">
                <h:form id="formEliminar">
                    <h:outputText value="¿Desesa eliminar?"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Si" actionListener="#{eliminarAsesorManagedBean.eliminarAsesor()}" 
                                     oncomplete="dlg.hide()"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="dlg.hide();"/>
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
            <!--Fin Borrar Asesor Dialogo-->
```

And this is my Managed Bean:

```
 public class EliminarAsesorManagedBean {
private Asesor selectedAsesor;
@Inject //Inyección de implementación 
private AsesorService asesorService;

public Asesor getSelectedAsesor() {
    return selectedAsesor;
}

public void setSelectedAsesor(Asesor selectedAsesor) {
    this.selectedAsesor = selectedAsesor;
}

public EliminarAsesorManagedBean() {
}

public void eliminarAsesor() throws IOException {
    asesorService.eliminarAsesor(selectedAsesor);
    ExternalContext con = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    con.redirect("administrarAsesores.xhtml");
}}
```

The problem is when i press "Si" on the confirm dialog, the log send a error:

```
attempt to create delete event with null entity
```

The code delete fine without the confirm dialog. I'm using NetBeans 8.2, Primefaces 6.0 and Hibernate 4.3

Comment: Best guess: the scope of your bean is to short (you sort of do not use a confirm dialog, but a normal dialog)

Comment: I also been try with confirm dialog and still not working.

Comment: Is the `Asesor` the entity? It must be null. What is the scope of your bean? Do logging in the setAsesor and the bean constructor/@PostConstruct annotated methods to see what happening under the scenes with the asesor field.

Comment: `oncomplete="PF('dlg').show();"` this will show your confirmation dialog when your delete call is completed.

Comment: `onclick="dlg.hide();"` -> `onclick="PF('dlg').hide();"`

Comment: @TheBitman My scope bean is a RequestScoped

Comment: @Holger still not working.

Comment: If your bean is `RequestScoped` then every call will recreate the bean (`Asesor=null`). For ajax always use at least `ViewScoped` beans.

Comment: Then how i can make to work?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem, i changed this:

```
@Named(value = "eliminarAsesorManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
```

To:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "eliminarAsesorManagedBean")
@ViewScoped
```